# Empty zip file size shows 22 bytes size

Tags: file-management, zip, ios, file-corruption

I want to separate Empty Zip files & Corrupted zip files in general simple way. I can see 22 bytes for empty zip files.
So, my question is :

> 1. Always empty zip files will be **22 bytes** (or say less than 100bytes) ?
> 2. How to categorize **empty & corrupt zip files** ?

I am into iOS platform and I need a general solution.

Comment: How do do you define 'corrupt' ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As given in the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format))

> The minimum size of a .ZIP file is 22 bytes**. Such empty zip file contains only an End of Central Directory Record (EOCD):
>
> ```
> [0x50,0x4B,0x05,0x06,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00]
> ```
>
> The maximum size for both the archive file and the individual files inside it is 4,294,967,295 bytes (2<sup>32</sup>−1 bytes, or 4 GiB minus 1 byte) for standard .ZIP, and 18,446,744,073,709,551,615 bytes (2<sup>64</sup>−1 bytes, or 16 EiB minus 1 byte) for ZIP64.

Hence I given a condition "*if the zip file size greater than 22 Bytes and not able to open*" then there is a chance of corrupt.

Comment: and if it's not corrupt, it's a rather worthless file anyway (doesn't contain any useful data).  Don't bother saving the useless 22 byte files.